# time picker with arrow up and down in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

need a time picker with up and down arrow key

when user click on up arrow whole time will up by 15 minutes not Indivisual time like hour or minute

can any give any idea or reference.

Comment: Is maximum value exists or no?

Answer (score 1):

Look at jQuery-UI spinner widget: [jQuery-UI Spinner](http://jqueryui.com/spinner/#time)

Comment: Is it possible to increase or decrease minute 15 at one click in this plugin

Comment: Check source from suggested link. You only need to change step option from `60 * 1000` to `15 * 60 * 1000`

Comment: thanks for your valuable input but i having problem for including this plugin so i decided to develop my own.

Answer (score 0):

in html5 you can use normal text field set attribute  to Input Type : Number it support by google chrome I don't know other browsers

```
<input id="user_lic" type="number" min="5" max="60" step="15" value ="5"/>
```

Comment: yes i m using html5. time format like HH:MM Am or PM. user can not enter value in text box he will able to change time only by arrow button.